# Use IPictureDisp objects from OLE Automation in Python COM Server running with LocalServer32

Tags: python, com, pywin32

I'm trying to setup a COM server with no admin rights so I can run a Word add-in that communicates with the Python Interpreter. The problem occurs when I assign IPictureDisp objects to python while running it in a localserver.

Registering the addin as a InProcServer32 works, but the code that I've found that register the addin as InProcServer requires elevation (admin rights). Since I need this to run without admin rights I've used the below solution to run COM as localserver.

```
def RegisterClass(cls):
    file = sys.modules[cls.__module__].__file__
    folder = os.path.dirname(file)
    module = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    python = win32com.server.register._find_localserver_exe(1)
    python = win32api.GetShortPathName(python)
    server = win32com.server.register._find_localserver_module()
    command = '%s "%s" %s' % (python, server, cls._reg_clsid_)
    typename = module + "." + cls.__name__

def write(path, value):
    win32api.RegSetValue(win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path, win32con.REG_SZ, value)

write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\" + cls._reg_progid_ + '\\CLSID', cls._reg_clsid_)
write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\AppID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_, cls._reg_progid_)
write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_, cls._reg_desc_)
write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\LocalServer32', command)
write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\ProgID', cls._reg_progid_)
write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\PythonCOMPath', folder)
write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\PythonCOM', typename)
write("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + cls._reg_clsid_ + '\\Debugging', "0")
```

But when running a localserver instead of getting a COM object for IPictureDisp objects, I get a message saying "Automation error: Catastrophic failure" from Word.

Is it possible to either run InProcServer as current user only (no admin) or make IPictureDisp objects work on LocalServer32?